# Why my Countdown function with setTimeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript

So I developed a countdown function, in the code below I test it with a 1 minute input, but the console throws all the values at once. What should happen is a number every second, I believe the problem is that setTimeout is probably not working, but how to fix?

```
 function countdown(tempominutos) {
    let tempo = new Date();
    tempo.setHours(0, tempominutos, 0);
    let tempoformatado = tempo.toLocaleTimeString();
    console.log(tempoformatado);
    while ((tempo.getSeconds() > 0) || (tempo.getMinutes() > 0) || (tempo.getHours() > 0)) {
      tempo.setSeconds(tempo.getSeconds() - 1);
      tempoformatado = tempo.toLocaleTimeString();
      setTimeout(console.log(tempoformatado), 1000);
    }
  }
  countdown(1);
```

Comment: setTimeout doesn't block function execution, but only schedules some work for later

Comment: The console.log within setTimeout runs, but instantly. It does not wait for the programmed 1 second (1000 ms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

**Firstly**, `setTimeout`'s first argument is a function, you're providing `console.log(tempoformatado)` which will execute `console.log` and evaluate to `undefined`.

You can solve this by wrapping your statement with a function:

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log(tempoformatado) }, 1000);
```

**Secondly**, you are using the same timeout for all your callbacks. You need to keep in mind that your `while` loop is executing instantly. All timeouts will have finished at the exact same time and almost 1000ms after the initial `tempoformatado` log.

To counter that you need to make the interval dependent to the time you're showing. For example you could calculate 1000ms times the number of seconds:

```
1000*tempo.getSeconds()
```

**Finally**, you need to make `tempoformatado` local to the `while` block. This makes sure that each loop as its own value of `tempoformatado`. You can do this by redefining `tempoformatado` with the `let` keyword inside the `while` loop

```js
function countdown(tempominutos) {
  let tempo = new Date();
  tempo.setHours(0, tempominutos, 0);
  let tempoformatado = tempo.toLocaleTimeString();
  console.log(tempoformatado);
  while ((tempo.getSeconds() > 0) || (tempo.getMinutes() > 0) || (tempo.getHours() > 0)) {
    tempo.setSeconds(tempo.getSeconds() - 1);
    let tempoformatado = tempo.toLocaleTimeString();
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(tempoformatado)
    }, 1000*tempo.getSeconds());
  }
}
countdown(1);
```

Comment: I ended up finding another problem with the code, but the setTimeout problem was solved. I will study what you said until you understand. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code expects setTimeout to work like a sleep function.

Instead, replace it with the sleep function defined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/6801443

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function countdown(tempominutos) {
  let tempo = new Date();
  tempo.setHours(0, tempominutos, 0);
  let tempoformatado = tempo.toLocaleTimeString();
  console.log(tempoformatado);
  while ((tempo.getSeconds() > 0) || (tempo.getMinutes() > 0) || (tempo.getHours() > 0)) {
    tempo.setSeconds(tempo.getSeconds() - 1);
    await sleep(1000);
    tempoformatado = tempo.toLocaleTimeString();
    console.log(tempoformatado);
  }
}
countdown(1);
```